# Change the td padding for only one table, not effect style of other tables?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have several tables and want to pad them differently. I've tried the following:

```
table#mapTable > tr > td{
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 20px !important;
}
```

for table with the id `'mapTable'`, but it hasn't been working (nothing happens). Same result, when trying `'margin-bottom'` rather than `'padding-bottom'`.

Is it possible to change `<td>` padding of only one table? I have a custom `<td>` style that I don't want to mess with for all the other tables.

For completeness, here's the table:

```
<table id='mapTable'>
      <tr><td>stuff</td><td>stuff</td></tr>
      <tr><td>info</td><td>info</td></tr>
</table>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are selecting the tds wrong. Do not use `>` just use spaces.

Spaces find elements that are children of the previous listed element.

```css
table#mapTable tr td{
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 20px !important;
}
```

```html
<table id='mapTable'>
      <tr><td>stuff</td><td>stuff</td></tr>
      <tr><td>info</td><td>info</td></tr>
</table>
<table id='noStyle'>
      <tr><td>stuff</td><td>stuff</td></tr>
      <tr><td>info</td><td>info</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Table cells do not inherit global styling or class styling. I have used some code that affected only the BG color of each cell, but it was JS based. I still have to manually style each th / td, but at least I can call up a styling class for general use.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to select `table#mapTable tr td`

It's enough to write

```
#mapTable td { 
  padding-left: 4px;
  padding-bottom: 20px !important;
}
```

(= all `<td>` elements inside id "mapTable")

Answer (score 2):

You got an answer already, just some more explanation:

`table > tr` won’t ever match table rows – because table rows *never are* children of a `table`.

They are children of a `tbody`, `thead` or `tfoot` element. The fact that there is no such element in your HTML code is not relevant here – in that situation, browsers create a `tbody` element *implicitly* when creating the DOM – they *have* to, because the specification says so.

You can easily verify that using your browser’s DOM inspector. Even for your minimal table example above, you’ll see that there is a `tbody`.

Comment: Thanks very much for the expanded explanation. I'm just starting to get into the more complicated DOM programming; that's great info.